# Overriding onInterceptTouchEvent in extension method

Tags: android, kotlin

Is it possible to override the `onInterceptTouchEvent` method of `ViewPager` in an extension method like we do for `onTouch` Event

```
fun ViewPager.disableSwiping(): ViewPager {

    this.onInterceptTouchEvent = { ... }

    this.setOnTouchListener(object : View.OnTouchListener {
        override fun onTouch(v: View?, event: MotionEvent?): Boolean {
            return true
        }
    })
    return this
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No.

The `onInterceptTouchEvent` is declared as:

```
@Override
public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev)
```

You can't override method in extension function - they are resolved statically.

In case of `setOnTouchListener`, you don't override `ViewPager` method, but override method of anonymous object of type `View.OnTouchListener`, and pass that to `ViewPager` method as normal argument - no magic.